# If $n$ is prime, is $(n-1)!+1$ always divisible by $n$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

It seems to hold through the 5000th prime. It's easy to see that it doesn't hold for composite $n$.

Comment: In fact, the converse is also true.

Answer (score 7):

Yes.  This is [Wilson's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilson%27s_theorem).

Comment: You first, +1 :)

Comment: If $n$ is composite, $(n-1)!$ is divisible by $n$ unless $n=4$

Answer (score 0):

Proof of Wilson theorem using factorial expansion:

Expansion of $(n-1)!$ is:

$(p-1)!=(p-1)^{p-1}-\frac{p-1}{1!}.(p-2)^{p-1}+\frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}.(p-3)^{p-1}-\frac{(p-1)(p-2)(p-3)}{3!}.(p-4)^{p-1}+ . . .$

Where the number of terms is $(p-1)$. If p is prime then all factors $p-1$, $p-2$, $p-3$, etc are primes to it, so due to Fermat;s little theorem each expansion of $(p-1)^{p-1}$, $(p-2)^{p-1}$ etc are of form $M(p)+1$; where $M(p)$ denotes 'a multiple of $p$'.Hence we can write:

$(p-1)!=[1-\frac{p-1}{1!}+\frac{(p-1)(p-2)}{2!}- . . .]+M(p)$

But the sum between bracelets is the binomial expansion of $(1-1)^{p-1}$, so we have:

$(p-1)!=[(1-1)^{p-1}-(-1)^{p-1}]+M(p)$

Considering that p is odd we finally get:

$(p-1)!=M(p)-1$

Or:

$p|(p-1)!+1$